# Is sharing data between apps with shared UID, and deleting data when last app is uninstalled possible?

Tags: android

I currently have several apps sharing the same user ID, and sharing simple data through a file on external storage. 
What I would like to know is, if there is a way to share data between applications that has the following characteristics:

1. Only apps with the same user ID have access to the data.
2. ALL apps with the shared UID have read/write access.
3. It isn't dependent on  a specific app (if I have 4 apps it will work fine with any combination of these).
4. And here is the tricky part: once the last app with the UID is uninstalled the data is deleted also.

Basically the data should be owned  by all the applications/the shared UID rather than any individual application.
As far as I can see none of the standard data storage possibilities live up to these requirements, and I was wondering if there would be any way of achieving this.
thanks in advance!

Comment: "As far as I can see non of the standard data storage possibilities live up to these requirements" -- correct. That's in part because `android:sharedUserId` is designed for firmware apps, and those are not uninstalled.

Comment: Thanks. If let's say point 4 were sacrificed, would a solution be possible?

Comment: There is nothing built in that will offer that, either. Moreover, #4 may be non-negotiable from the user's standpoint. Otherwise, if they uninstall whatever app you decided was "the one magic app" that held the user's data, now that data is lost, even for the other apps of yours that are already on the device. The only way this can be practical is if there is a clear master-slave relationship among the apps (e.g., there is really only one app plus a handful of plugins that happen to be implemented as apps, but are not expected to work in isolation).